# Parsing JS in Scala Play

Tags: json, scala, playframework

The objective is to find the id of the person that has a Porsche as a car from the following json:

```
{
    "people": [
        {
           "id": "1",
           "name": "John",
           "car": "Ford"
        },
        {
           "id": "2",
           "name": "Andrew",
           "car": "Porsche"
        },
        {
           "id": "3",
           "name": "Joshua",
           "car": "Mercedes"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using this as an example: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonCombinators, I can't find any code that'll allow me to do this:

Find the node in the people array that has a car value of "Porsche", then retrieve the ID from that node.

```
val cars = json \ "people" \\ "car"
```

returns a list of cars, but this isn't what I want to do.

Is there an easy way to do queries on the Json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following. First create a case class which represents the json structure.

```
case class Person(id: String, name: String, car: String)

object Person {
 implicit val personFormat = Json.format[Person]
}

case class People(people: List[Person])

object People {
  implicit val peopleFormat = Json.format[People]
}
```

**Scala REPL**

```
Now parse the json
scala> val str = """
     | {
     |     "people": [
     |         {
     |            "id": "1",
     |            "name": "John",
     |            "car": "Ford"
     |         },
     |         {
     |            "id": "2",
     |            "name": "Andrew",
     |            "car": "Porsche"
     |         },
     |         {
     |            "id": "3",
     |            "name": "Joshua",
     |            "car": "Mercedes"
     |         }
     |     ]
     | }
     | """.trim

scala> Json.parse(str).validate[People]
res5: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[People] = JsSuccess(People(List(Person(1,John,Ford), Person(2,Andrew,Porsche), Person(3,Joshua,Mercedes))),/people)

scala> Json.parse(str).validate[People] match {
     | case JsSuccess(value, _) => value.people.collectFirst { case Person(id, _, "Porsche") => id }
     | case JsError(errors) => None
     | }
res7: Option[String] = Some(2)
```

Finally parse and collect first

```
Json.parse(str).validate[People] match {
  case JsSuccess(value, _) => value.people.collectFirst { case Person(id, _, "Porsche") => id }
  case JsError(errors) => None
}
```